# command to write to physicaldrive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, writing

I have a bat file that we use to write meaningless data to a harddisk. But I dont know what exactly it means...

Here is the command:

```
dtlite2 of=\\.\physicaldrive1 bs=256k limit=200m passes=1000 disable=cache pat_part1=0xffffffff pat_part2=0xffffffff pat_part3=0x0 pat_part4=0x0 dlimit=2048
```

platform is windows. This is run from a bat file.

Comment: dtlite2; isn't it daemon tools?

Comment: I dont know, at first I thought so but I cannot find any documentation on deamon tools lite that points to any of it mean. I assume bs is block size. passes is how many passes it does but what does limit do? or disable-cache? etc...